# Detecting an error in a loop

Tags: r, error-handling

The following:

```
install.packages("quantreg")
require(quantreg)

y=rnorm(10)
x=rnorm(10)

summary(rq(y~x,tau=0.01),se="ker")
```

Generates the error `Error in summary.rq(rq(y ~ x, tau = 0.01), se = "ker") : 
  tau - h < 0:  error in summary.rq`.

Say I loop over different `y` and `x` 1000 times. I want to be able to know when the error occurs and implement a fix mid-loop.

However all my attempts to work with `summary(rq(y~x,tau=0.01),se="ker")` using `is()` etc etc doesn't get anywhere. I've never worked with this object type before (and Google/SE searches haven't revealed the answer yet).

I want something like `is.error(summary(rq(y~x,tau=0.01),se="ker"))`, which doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will return a logical value indicating whether an error occured:

```
class(tryCatch(summary(rq(y ~ x,tau = 0.01),se = "ker"),
               error = function(e) e))[1] == "simpleError"
```

You can use `replicate` instead of a for loop. It is more efficient. In the follwing example, a list including `x`, `y`, and the logical `error`value is returned. The procedure is replicated two times. You could use `n = 1000` to replicate it 1000 times.

```
replicate(n = 2,
          expr = {y <- rnorm(10);
                  x <- rnorm(10);
                  error <- class(tryCatch(summary(rq(y ~ x,tau = 0.01),se = "ker"), error = function(e) e))[1] == "simpleError";
                  return(list(x = x, y = y, error = error))},
          simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the answer from @SvenHohenstein one would like to return the result on successful evaluation, not just whether an error occurred. We'd likely also want to return the reason for the error message using `conditionMessage`. We'd like to catch errors of class `simpleError`, so we write a handlers specific to that type of condition. So

```
error <- FALSE              # no error yet
result <- tryCatch({        # result from summary(), or from the error handler
    summary(rq(y ~ x,tau = 0.01),se = "ker")
}, simpleError = function(e) {  # only catch simpleErrors
    error <<- TRUE      # yes, error occurred
    conditionMessage(e) # 'result' gets error message
})
```

we'd then return `list(x = x, y = y, error=error, result=result)`.